# OpenCV - Highlight mouth region after detection

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I want to extract only the rectangular part of the mouth detected by my code how can I do it:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
mouth_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_smile.xml')
img = cv2.imread('Images/image_0033.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    mouth = mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray,2.0,25)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in mouth:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),3)

cv2.imshow('img',nwimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As seen in the code I just want to extract the rectangular mouth region I have used commands like `var = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]` but this has not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, replace this line:

`cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),3)` with

`cv2.rectangle(img,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),3)`

and display the following:

`cv2.imshow('Detected Mouth',img)`

In this way you will draw a rectangle over the mouth.

**EDIT**

You can crop your region of interest (in this case the mouth) using `numpy` operation as follows:

```
crop_img = img[ey:ey+eh, ex:ex+ew]
cv2.imshow('Cropped Mouth',crop_img)
```

This is what I got:

**Sample 1:**

[image]

[image]

**Sample 2:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have detected mouth from face now I want to perform imwrite() command and the image should only be the mouth and not whole face how to do this